# Multiple Agregate Roots based on the same entity depending on business context

Tags: c#, .net-core, architecture, domain-driven-design

I'm trying to put my hands on DDD pattern using .Net C#. I checked multiple soultions, tutorials, articles but most of them are utilising same simple idea - an Order entity, with Items etc. What I'm trying to understand, what whould be suitable design for (oversimplified for sake of this discussion) case below.

Lets say we have 3 entities.

```
class Company
{
public int Id {get;set;}
public string Name {get;set;}
}

class BusinessService{
public int Id {get;set;}
public int CompanyId {get;set;}
public string Name {get;set;}
public double Price {get;set;}
}

class Vehicle{
public int Id {get;set;}
public int CompanyId {get;set;}
public string CarPlate {get;set;}
}
```

In this case Company can have BusinessServices, which should be used for creating i.e invoices and Vehicles which can be used in web application to present company user vehicles bounded to his company. As DDD points, I should create CompanyRootAggregate containing readonly collections of BusinessServices and Vehicles. But this does not make much sense because when I'm working with business/financial scope I don't need information about vehicles and when user is working with application context he does not need information about business services. Having both colletions in root is redundant depending on calling context. It would present to much data to some parts of application, not to mention about overloading DB.

What approach should be applied to resolve this? Should application be divided into sub domains in which we can define CompanyAggretationRoot, which differes depeneding on sub domain context (i.e CompanyBusinessAggregationRoot with BusinessService collection and CompanyVehicleAggregationRoot with Vehicle collection?) Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Two solution,

-First solution split in different folder or project

You can split with multiple web application (microservice) each have the own aggregate, but same database.

You can split with same project, but split by feature

```
Compagnie.Domain
 / Business
    / Aggregates
       / CompanyBusinessAggregationRoot.cs
    / Commands
    / Queries
 / Vehicle
    /Aggregates 
       / CompanyVehicleAggregationRoot.cs
    / Commands
    / Queries
```

-Second solution for performance purpose you can use Repository with differente include and not load all data for some purpose.
Example: put ICompanyBusinessAggregationRoot interface on the aggregate.
When you call your repository you do `GetCompagny<ICompanyBusinessAggregationRoot>()` and you put include on DbContext   determined by interface.
And do the same for ICompanyBusinessAggregationRoot, after you can use interface for access to the data used by command or query

```
public class CompanyAggregationRoot : ICompanyVehicleAggregationRoot, ICompanyBusinessAggregationRoot
```